# Shell Script that touches multiple other machines over ssh?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have a list of linux machines, about 90 or so.

These are saved in a file as Host,USR,PW.
Is there a way I can read this list and then connect to each host and execute commands X, Y, Z

In the past I have touched each machine separately and just executed the commands by hand.
Takes FOREVER. There must be a better way.

Comment: This question would be perfectly on-topic on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com), where it [has](http://serverfault.com/q/13322/48279) [been](http://serverfault.com/q/2533/48279) [asked](http://serverfault.com/q/155172/48279) [many](http://serverfault.com/q/203163/48279) [times](http://serverfault.com/q/143671/48279) [already](http://serverfault.com/q/17931/48279).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH batch mode should do it.  Discussed here: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/how-to-execute-ssh-and-scp-in-batch-mode-only-when-passwordless-login-is-enabled/

`ssh -o "BatchMode yes" ramesh@remote-host who`

to use usernames and passwords you might need to do some work with expect.  using pre-shared keys is required for batch mode

Answer (score 2):

[Func](https://fedorahosted.org/func/)

[ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/)

Answer (score 2):

See :

[Fanout and Fanterm](http://www.stearns.org/fanout/README.html)
[DSH - distributed shell](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en)

Answer (score 1):

You could use ssh with authentication keys.

So you could connect to every server with ssh and execute your commands.

Explained here -> http://www.debian-administration.org/article/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password

to read out the file you can use awk to filter only the hosts

cat file.txt | awk { print $1 } (don't know the file so this is an example)

Comment: yea but that means I would need to setup keys with every machine first =/

Comment: for sure. its an initial work, so after that it would make automation a lot more easier. If you have an Windows machine you could try with powershell and plink to achieve the same result (plink can be used with username and password) -> http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MCollective](http://www.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/introduction/) from Puppet Labs and the plugin [shellcmd-agent](http://www.joeym.net/2010/09/27/shellcmd-agent-execute-any-shell-command-in-parallel-on-multiple-machines-with-mcollective/).